# Using bold for just one word inside listing?

Tags: listings, bold

I have a similar structure like this:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=bash]
Family
|-father
|-mother
|-elderson
|-younger son
|-younger daughter
\end{lstlisting}
```

I need to make "mother" and "younger daughter" words in bold. How can I do it? 
i followed this [Using bold/italic text inside listings?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27663/using-bold-italic-text-inside-listings/27677), but could not do it.

Comment: Why couldn't you succeed with the linked answer? What error were you getting?

Comment: I am not getting any error. The words are not getting bold.

Comment: What font are you using?

Comment: i think I am using [utf8]{inputenc}. Is this correct?

Comment: That's not a font, that is the encoding of the input file. You should use one of the fonts they list in the linked answer, such as  `\usepackage{pxfonts}`

Comment: ok. i will check that

Comment: Is this correct?
`\lstset{language=bash,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    keywordstyle=\bfseries,
    showstringspaces=false,
    morekeywords={mother, younger daughter}
}`

Comment: I don't know, did it work?

Comment: No, It didn't work. but i found the solution here. [link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33039/using-ttfamily-with-bfseries-or-how-to-enable-bold-in-fixed-width-font/33041#33041)

Comment: Glad you got it figured out! When you tried the first `\lstset` method, had you put `\usepackage{pxfonts}` in your preamble?

Comment: No I did not use `\usepackage{pxfonts}`. I do not know that I have to use that later when Karlkoeller mentioned regarding the font in my document, everything got cleared.