# How to use slanted text inside a code?

Tags: listings, slanted

I have a code for which I am using

```
\begin{lstlisting} 
line1 
line2
line3
\end{lstlisting}
```

I want to show the line1 and line3 as slanted. How this can be done ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using bold/italic text inside listings?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27663/using-bold-italic-text-inside-listings)

Comment: @MaartenDhondt : Thanks. But probably that will not solve my problem . I have a JVML code of about 10 lines, and I do not want to make the keywords different looking. For explanation purpose I need some of the lines of my code to be slanted ( or of different color or may be boldfaced. I just need those lines to look different from others, that's it).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  Please take a moment to take our [Tour](http://tex.stackexchange.com/tour)!  You may also want to look at what makes a good Minimal Working Example ([MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that))

Answer (score 3):

You can use delimiters:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
  basicstyle = \ttfamily ,
  moredelim = [is][\itshape]{|}{|}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=mystyle]
|line1 
line2|
line3
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\begin{lstlisting}[style=mystyle]
|line1| 
line2
|line3|
\end{lstlisting}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the complexities, one might be able to use the optional argument of the `verbatimbox` environments to achieve this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatimbox,xcolor}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\formatting{%
\ifnum\theVerbboxLineNo=1\relax\slshape\fi%
\ifnum\theVerbboxLineNo=3\relax\slshape\fi%
}
\begin{verbbox}[\formatting]
line1 
line2
line3
\end{verbbox}
This is my code: \fbox{\theverbbox}

\renewcommand\formatting{%
\ifnum\theVerbboxLineNo=1\relax\slshape\fi%
\ifnum\theVerbboxLineNo=3\itshape\leavevmode%
  \smash{\rlap{\color{red!20}\rule[-\dp\strutbox]{27pt}{\baselineskip}}}\fi%
}
\begin{verbbox}[\formatting]
line1 
line2
line3
line4
\end{verbbox}
This is my revised code: \fbox{\theverbbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]