# Escape listings but keep colour formatting

Tags: color, listings, bold, typewriter

## Getting bold typed text

I have been using `listings` to format my code, and have occasionally been using the following solution to make some typed text bold:

```
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{cmtt}{bx}{n}{<5><6><7><8><9><10><10.95><12><14.4><17.28><20.74><24.88>cmttb10}{}
```

(I have no idea how this works, but is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9438643/5134817) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/102555/106804)).

However, I usually use this with black text, but have just noticed that ***this does not preserve the colour the `listings` package gives when highlighting***.

## It doesn't work within a coloured `listings`

[image]

## MWE

```
\documentclass[10pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{stringstyle=\color[rgb]{.627,.126,.941}, basicstyle={\fontfamily{cmtt}\selectfont\footnotesize},showstringspaces=false} 
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{cmtt}{bx}{n}{<5><6><7><8><9><10><10.95><12><14.4><17.28><20.74><24.88>cmttb10}{}
\begin{document}
\ttfamily Something in \textbf{bold}. {\color{red} Something else in \textbf{bold}.}
\begin{lstlisting}[escapechar=@]
Something @\textbf{important}@ right here. 
\end{lstlisting}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C, escapechar=@]
int main() 
{
    int = 1;
    char * s = "@something@ @\textbf{important}@ right @\color[rgb]{.627,.126,.941} \bfseries here@" 
               "and a normal string for comparison";
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

***Is it possible to have `@\textbf{...}@` inherit the colour `listings` wants to give it?***

Answer (score 3):

One way to get the desired result is to redefine strings as delimiters. We define a new language based on the C language. Then we delete the default string definition with `deletestring=[b]"` and replace it with a new delimited environment with `moredelim=**[s][...]{"}{"}`. The `**` tells `listings` to accumulate styles inside this environment such that we can define `@...@` as another one that sets the bold font inside it. There's no need to escape listings now anymore.

The disadvantage of the `**` delimiter type is that it also accumulates styles of keywords and other special syntax elements that occur inside of string literals. To prevent that, we have to define a new toggle that keeps track of whether we currently are inside a string literal or not. The toggle is set to true as part of the string literal style and reset via the `EndGroup` hook, which is executed everytime `listings` leaves a delimiter.

A new command `\nostringstyle` is defined that has to be used whenever a style is set for the various syntax elements (like in `keywordstyle`). Based on the toggle state, the style then is only applied if that element occurs outside of string literals.

Full example code (also note the bold "int" keyword):

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\makeatletter
\newif\if@instring
\@instringfalse

\newcommand\nostringstyle[1]{\if@instring\else#1\fi}
\lst@AddToHook{EndGroup}{\global\@instringfalse}

\lstset{
    basicstyle={\fontfamily{cmtt}\selectfont\footnotesize},
}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{cmtt}{bx}{n}{<5><6><7><8><9><10><10.95><12><14.4><17.28><20.74><24.88>cmttb10}{}

\lstdefinelanguage{myC}[ANSI]{C}{
    deletestring=[b]",
    keywordstyle={\nostringstyle{\color{blue}}},
    moredelim=**[s][{\global\@instringtrue\color[rgb]{.627,.126,.941}}]{"}{"},
    moredelim=**[is][{\bfseries}]{@}{@},
    showstringspaces=false
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\noindent\ttfamily Something in \textbf{bold}. {\color{red} Something else in \textbf{bold}.}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=myC]
int main()
{
    @int@ = 1;
    char * s = "something @important@ right @here@" 
               "and a normal string for comparison";
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is almost what I was after, but I was hoping to have `@...@` be some escape that allowed for some extra formatting, so while in my example I may use bold, I an/could instead choose `@\textit{something}@`, or even `@$something$@`. In what I am expecting to use it for though I am mostly expecting to use either bold, italics, underline, strikethrough, etc. (nothing too exotic, bit to support a few features, mostly bold though).

Comment: `listings`' capabilities are really limited here. For bold and italics text my solutions works fine. For underline or strikethrough you can use the approach presented [in this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/456194/23765). I'm not sure how a solution for math mode could look like, as `listings` executes the `EndGroup` hook when it escapes the listing, so all information about the `\@instring` toggle ist lost.